# Inherit category layout update in magento in catalog.xml

Tags: inheritance, layout, magento, catalog

I know I can set a single category layout through catalog.xml using

```
<CATEGORY_123>
  <reference name="left">
    <block type=""> (etc.)
  </reference>
</CATEGORY>
```

(thanks @Greg for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196231/update-left-column-for-certain-category-how-to-set-category-id-in-layout-file))

How can I set this update for the single category and all its children categories?

Answer (score 1):

Using Catalog.xml I'm not sure if you can. However, if you go to your category in the administration and click on the Custom Design tab, you can put your XML there and specify whether child categories/product inherit the XML (using the "Apply To" dropdown).

Answer (score 0):

You can add the layout update in Custom Design section of your Category, then set all children categories to use the parent settings

[image]